# Which normality test if only 5 samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Which is the appropriate test to test normality if there are only 5 samples?
I know that Shapiro-Wilk test doesn't work for small size samples. Is Kolmogorov-Smirnov test appropriate?

Thank you

Comment: Look at this - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13983/is-it-meaningful-to-test-for-normality-with-a-very-small-sample-size-e-g-n

Comment: A Shapiro-Wilk can be done with $n=3$. In what sense do you mean "doesn't work" and how do you know it?

Comment: You might also like to expand on why you wish to test for normality.